# Selenium grid not working in internet explorer 11

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Selenium Grid and Hub working perfectly fine and running accordingly, but I'm unable to run the tests on https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g1x1.png and **selenium-standalone v2.53**.

**My grid console:**

[image]

**My error:**

[image]

```
public class testSample {

@Test
public void testLogin() throws MalformedURLException
{
    DesiredCapabilities cap= DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    cap.setBrowserName("iexplore");
    cap.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);

    RemoteWebDriver driver= new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),cap);

    driver.get("http://demo.bigideasmath.com/BIM/login");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='loginForm']/div[1]/div/input")).sendKeys("aaaaa");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='loginForm']/div[2]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("bcbcb");
    driver.quit();

}
}
```

Comment: java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\software\IEDriverServer.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 6987 -browser browserName=iexplore,maxInstances=5

Comment: Not entirely sure what the question is. Are you trying to run this script on a Selenium Grid or are you trying to connect to the Selenium Webdriver directly?